# Failed to lookup view in node.js ejs template while the template is only just renamed

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a node.js application rendering in ejs 3 template.
let 's say -there is one template, course.ejs, it used to work well in node.js.

```
res.render('course', locals);
```

However, today when I tried to change the content, let 's say - course.ejs, it doesn't take effect, there is no error with node.js application and the data passed to the template is all right.

I even copy-pasted the content of this template, and make a new template with a different name - course1.ejs. and change my code to

```
res.render('course1', locals);
```

then when the app runs again, it pops up a error saying

### Error: Failed to lookup view "course1" template.

The code in node.js and template are all right, it is supposed to work in the ways above. Why it doesn't work now. I have my ejs version 0.8.3, while express in 3.1.0 and node.js in 0.10.0

This is my app configuration.

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views',__dirname+'/views');

    app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));

  app.use(express.compress({
    filter: function (req, res) {
      return /json|text|javascript|css/.test(res.getHeader('Content-Type'));
    },
    level: 9
  }));  

    app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:__dirname+'/public/uploads',keepExtensions: true,limit: '50mb'}));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ 
                      cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }
                      ,store: sessionStore
                      ,secret: config.sessionSecret
                      ,key: 'express.sid'
                      ,clear_interval: 3600
    }));


    app.use(express.csrf()); 
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
      res.locals.token = req.session._csrf;
      next();
    });


    app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));   

}
```

#### my static files is in the public folder, and all the templates are in the view folder.

I wonder has anyone met this kind of problem before

Comment: Could it be you also have a `course.html` somewhere that's being served by `express.static`? Also, show us your Express application setup (`app.use`, `app.configure`, etc).

Comment: In my static file folder, there are just css, js, image files, no html. and all the templates,  it can show but when changed, it won't update the editted content

Comment: Yeah I was mistaken with the `express.static` suggestion, but if you have a `course.html` in your *views* folder it might be causing the problems. See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think this configuration can work if your templates have the `.ejs` extension:

```
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Using that configuration, Express will look for `TEMPLATENAME.html` when you call `res.render('TEMPLATENAME', ...)`, and not `TEMPLATENAME.ejs`. For that, you need this:

```
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

So that's the `course1` part solved: Express was looking for `course1.html`, which it couldn't find, so it would generate the error you got (`Failed to lookup view...`).

However, I don't see how rendering `course.ejs` could have worked. Perhaps you have another route which is handling the request you're testing? Or you have a `course.html` in the views folder (besides the `course.ejs`)?

Comment: Thanks, robert, it works, though I don't quite figure out why, the previous config had worked for me until I updated my node.js version from 0.8 to 0.10

Comment: In my views template folder, there are course_new.html, course_description.html, course_recent.html, additionly these htmls include the ejs based templates

Comment: Mixing `.ejs` files together with `.html` files might be the cause of your problems. The best solution would be to decide what your template filenames should get as extension, and only use that extension in the `views` folder.